# OIDs from net-snmp agentx not showing in smpwalk unless specified explicitly

Tags: net-snmp, snmpd

I've created custom SNMP agent and want it's output to be included in results returned by snmpwalk with no OID specified. OIDs appear when I specify it in the commandline:

```
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 192.168.0.145 .1.3.6.1.4.1.50536
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.50536.1.1.1.1.2.1 = STRING: "foo0"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.50536.1.1.1.1.3.1 = INTEGER: 5030
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.50536.1.1.1.1.4.1 = INTEGER: 5030
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.50536.1.1.1.1.5.1 = INTEGER: 5030
```

However, they don't appear when I don't specify my custom OID:

```
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 192.168.0.145 | grep 50536
$
```

I have `view systemview included .1.3.6.1.4.1.50536` in my `snmpd.conf`, this does not help

```
# cat /usr/local/etc/snmpd.conf 
agentAddress udp:161,udp6:161,unix:/var/run/snmpd.sock
sysLocation test
sysContact test
sysDescr Hardware: amd64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460  CPU @ 3.20GHz running at 3192 Software: FreeBSD 11.0-STABLE (revision 199506)

view   systemview  included   .1.3.6.1.4.1.50536
master agentx

rocommunity "public" default
iquerySecName initial
```

What else can be causing this problem?

Comment: How did you get your OIDs to appear at all?  When I do the same, I get `No Such Object available on this agent at this OID`.  Additionally, how are you running your OIDs through the master agent instead of a subagent (if that is what you're doing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, NET-SNMP snmpwalk walks 1.3.6.1.2.1, according to it's man page

http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpwalk.html